# Creating framework targets for iOS and watchOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, apple-watch, watchos

I'm planning to add an Apple Watch app to my iOS app. Large parts of my code (the data model and network layer etc) are located in two frameworks. I want to use these frameworks in the watch app as well. I found some example of how to create new watchOS targets for my frameworks:

1. Duplicate the existing target for the framework
2. Give it a unique name (In my case "RYMUtilsWatchKit")
3. Change "Supported Platforms" to "watchOS"
4. Change the "Base SDK" to "Latest watchOS"
5. Set the "Product name" to be identical to the original target, so that both targets build with the same name (In my case "RYMUtilsKit")

[image]

[image]

I then add the new framework target to my watch app extension in my main project.

[image]

[image]

However, when I build I get an error message saying:

> Target 'RYMUtilsKit' of project 'RYMUtilsKit' was rejected as an
>   implicit dependency for 'RYMUtilsKit.framework' because it doesn't
>   contain platform 'watchsimulator' in its supported platforms
>   'iphonesimulator, iphoneos'

So it seems it's trying to build the wrong target for my watch app extension. Shouldn't it build the "RYMUtilsWatchKit" target instead?

I'm obviously doing something wrong here...

Answer (score 1):

If you can use the frameworks which have the network layer and data models for both **iOS** and **WatchOS**, you don't have to duplicate your existing frameworks. You can create a single framework for multiple platforms. There is a good tutorial about this, on [Create Cross Platform Framework](https://github.com/TofPlay/SwiftCrossPlatformFramework).

Comment: `ERROR 410 - The author deleted this Medium story.` :(